# Set Select Dropbox Value using integer data type

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html-select

I am trying to set the value of a dropbox. The data returned by server is int type

Data format

```
data : {
    "profileID": "A000110A001XXX001",
    "profileName": "Profile Test",
    "profileState": "1002",
    "createDTime": "12-04-2013 14:16:43",
    "lfState": 4
}
```

Then setting the value for dropbox as

```
$("#lfState").val(data.lfState);
```

The HTML Select box code is

```
 <select name="lfState" id="lfState" >
    <option value="0">*** Select ***</option>
    <option value="1">Normal</option>
    <option value="2">Locked</option>
    <option value="3">Pending</option>
    <option value="4">Deleted</option>
</select>
```

The select box do not get pre-selected for value lfState and this happens in chrome only. The FF selects the value correctly.

Any inputs please.

Comment: Shouldn't that be something like `data.lfState`?

Comment: It is like that only. I edited the question

Comment: Something stupid like converting the integer to a string? toString()?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/Chhbj/ -- with Chrome

Comment: @dollarvar : Tried that as well and tried appending quotes around that but nothing worked.

Comment: Also on iOS, btw. So jQuery does type conversion again, huh? ;)

Comment: @tymeJV : the Fiddle seems to be working and the code as well if I hard code the date as int on the page but when I return the same data from server it does not work

Comment: Verify there are no spaces within the data returned, try trimming.

Comment: Oh, now you have a comma after the 4. Shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug in the application , it was not because of the integer value rather it was because of the way JavaScript was handling the ajax calls asynchronously.

So there were two calls one which was building the dropbox and one which gets the data from server.

In FF both the calls were in sequence i.e. synchronously ( I don't know why) .

In chrome they were happening asynchronously and that is why the data retrival was happing before the select box is build.

So I changed the calls to synchronous and it started working fine.